# Calling the list without be new every time

Tags: c#

```
public class ToDoServices
{
    List<TaskToDo> taskToDos { get; set; }
    private int number;

    public ToDoServices()
    {
        taskToDos = new();
    }
    
    public void AddToList()
    {
        number++;
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        string dateString = Console.ReadLine();
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
        taskToDos.Add(new TaskToDo { Id = number, Title = text, TimeToDo = dateTime });
        ReadWriteFile readWriteFile = new ReadWriteFile();
        readWriteFile.WriteToFiles();
    }
    
    public List<TaskToDo> ShowTheList()
    {
        foreach (var taskToDo in taskToDos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"To Do:{taskToDo.Id}: {taskToDo.Title}:{taskToDo.TimeToDo}");
        }
        return taskToDos;
    }
}

public class ReadWriteFile
{
    string fileName = @".\ToDo.txt";
    
    public void WriteToFiles()
    {
        ToDoServices toDoServices = new ToDoServices();
        var taskToDos = toDoServices.ShowTheList();
        using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
        {
            foreach (var i in taskToDos)
                writetext.WriteLine(i.Id + "-" + i.Title + " " + i.TimeToDo);
        }
    }
}

public class TaskToDo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeToDo { get; set; }
}
```

This project I am creating a list but I have a problem when I want to save this list in text file, when I call the list in class `ReadWriteFile`, the list be empty. I know it be new empty list because I call every time for new list.

I tried many ways but I didn't success, so I hope someone can help me to solve the problem/ thanks for help

Comment: Please edit your question and put the actual code, not an image of the code.  And read about [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) we prefer this.

Comment: When you create your `ReadWriteFile`, you need to pass it the instance of `ToDoServices`.

Comment: I tried by writing code but I got wrong and I couldn't submit the question

Comment: What was the error that you had that did not allow you to submit the question? Try again, it is preferred that you also get the formatting yourself correct, but if not, someone can also edit and fix the code formatting for you. Simplest way is type 4 backticks ````, paste your code, then 4 backticks again.

Comment: I have added ```` but it didn't work, it says fix formatting

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. The `ReadWriteFile` class does not have a reference to `taskToDos` and the `ToDoService` class doesn't have a `ShowTheList` method. You should fix those before asking anything about the code.

Comment: @user16168859 - Please don't edit questions that invalidates existing answers. Add any changes to the end of your question and explain why you're doing that.

Comment: @user16168859 - Please stop deleting those lines.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Thanks for answering the question and Iam so sorry for I was editing and deleting the question, I am still a new user I stack overflow , I thought I was doing better things to you and to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that your code's logic hasn't been well thought out.

If your `ReadWriteFile.WriteToFiles()` method you're calling `new ToDoServices()` and then attempting to write out the file, but you never call `toDoServices.AddToList()` to actually populate the list with anything - so the list is empty when you try to save it.

However, the `ToDoServices.AddToList()` method actually creates a new instance of `ReadWriteFile` and calls `readWriteFile.WriteToFiles()` - which means that if `WriteToFiles()` did call `AddToList()` you'd be in an infinite loop!

You need to separate out all of the logic so that each method does one thing and one thing only. the `AddToList()` method should only add an item to the list. The `ShowTheList()` method should only show the list.

This is closer to what you need:

```
void Main()
{
    string fileName = @".\ToDo.txt";
    ToDoServices toDoServices = new();
    toDoServices.AddToList();
    ReadWriteFile readWriteFile = new();
    readWriteFile.WriteToFiles(fileName, toDoServices);
}

public class ToDoServices
{
    private List<TaskToDo> taskToDos = new();
    private int number;

    public void AddToList()
    {
        number++;
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        string dateString = Console.ReadLine();
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
        taskToDos.Add(new TaskToDo { Id = number, Title = text, TimeToDo = dateTime });
    }

    public void ShowTheList()
    {
        foreach (var taskToDo in taskToDos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"To Do:{taskToDo.Id}: {taskToDo.Title}:{taskToDo.TimeToDo}");
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TaskToDo> GetTheList() => taskToDos.AsEnumerable();
}

public class ReadWriteFile
{
    public void WriteToFiles(string fileName, ToDoServices toDoServices)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
            foreach (var td in toDoServices.GetTheList())
                writetext.WriteLine($"{td.Id}-{td.Title} {td.TimeToDo}");
    }
}

public class TaskToDo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeToDo { get; set; }
}
```